# Krabs.js vs Next.js 12 middleware, rewrites

Tags: next.js, subdomain, middleware, multi-tenant, vercel

I am trying to find a good solution for implementing SSG in Next with Subdomains. I've seen that Next has come out with [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) and the [platform starter kit](https://demo.vercel.pub/platforms-starter-kit).
What I am trying to understand is if these offerings rely on use of Vercel.

I saw a cool middleware called [Krabs](https://github.com/micheleriva/krabs) that seems to solve this problem as well. If the new Next middleware is not coupled with Vercel, would it replace the need for Krabs if one only needs subdomains?

I also saw that some are using [rewrites](https://github.com/acorcutt/next-multi-host) to accomplish this.

I am trying to all these compare in April of 2022 and perhaps how they relate. I suppose I am at the beginning of my journey in understanding this topic, but I'm a few days in already and figured I should pose the question to y'all for help. Thank you very much